# Mongo reduce with switch-case multiple actions

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

In mongo4.2, during an aggregation I have an array field `values`, which is formed as follows:

```
values: [
  {_id: 'x', value: 1},
  {_id: 'y', value: 2},
  {_id: 'z', value: 3}
]
```

I want to produce an object field `stats` with `$addFields` in order to create specific keys with the specific data:

```
stats: {
  x: { value: 1 },
  y: { value: 2 },
  z: { value: 3 },
  total: 1+2+3=6
}
```

I have this stage so far

```
$addFields: {
  stats: {
    $reduce: {
      input: '$values',
      initialValue: {
        x: {
          value: 0,
        },
        y: {
          value: 0,
        },
        z: {
          value: 0,
        },
        total: 0
      },
      in: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            { case: { $eq: [ '$$this._id', 'x' ] }, then: { $mergeObjects: ['$$value', {'x': {'value': '$$this.value'}}]} },
            { case: { $eq: [ '$$this._id', 'y' ] }, then: { $mergeObjects: ['$$value', {'y': {'value': '$$this.value'}}]} },
            { case: { $eq: [ '$$this._id', 'z' ] }, then: { $mergeObjects: ['$$value', {'z': {'value': '$$this.value'}}]} },
          default: '$$value'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My question; is there a way to "squeeze" another action in the the `in` stage of the `$reduce` in order to compute the `total` without the need of an extra `$addFields` stage or a second `$reduce` for a separate field?

Comment: Doubt that it is possible to achieve within single `$addFields` stage. Second `$reduce` will be the choice but it makes the query more complex.

Comment: Thanks, I feared so. In that case I'll probably use a `$facet` in the `$group` stage that generates the `values` field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `$mergeObjects`, add `total` in the second object. Like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      stats: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$values",
          initialValue: {
            x: {
              value: 0,
              
            },
            y: {
              value: 0,
              
            },
            z: {
              value: 0,
              
            },
            total: 0
          },
          in: {
            $switch: {
              branches: [
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this._id",
                      "x"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "x": {
                          "value": "$$this.value"
                        },
                        total: {
                          "$add": [
                            "$$value.total",
                            "$$this.value"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this._id",
                      "y"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "y": {
                          "value": "$$this.value"
                        },
                        total: {
                          "$add": [
                            "$$value.total",
                            "$$this.value"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                {
                  case: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this._id",
                      "z"
                    ]
                  },
                  then: {
                    $mergeObjects: [
                      "$$value",
                      {
                        "z": {
                          "value": "$$this.value"
                        },
                        total: {
                          "$add": [
                            "$$value.total",
                            "$$this.value"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              ],
              default: "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground link.](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zIzE8qHjzio)